# How to align subtables side by side instead of below each other

Tags: tables, subfloats

I am trying to get two subtables aligned next to one another but they're placed below one another, I've looked at multiple tutorials and questions here but I can't seem to get them aligned side by side.

An example of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \caption{CAPTION}
    
    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
            \caption{CAPTION}
            \begin{tabular}{| ccc | cccc |}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Single} \\
            \hline
            1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
            \hline\hline
            1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\ 
            \hline
            1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \label{subtab:.........}
    \end{subtable}
    
    \begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
            \caption{CAPTION}
            \begin{tabular}{| ccc | cccc |}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Single} \\
            \hline
            1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
            \hline\hline
            1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\ 
            \hline
            1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\ 
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \label{subtab:.........}
    \end{subtable}
    
    \label{tab:................}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You have a blank line between the two subtables..  That puts the processing into vertical mode, which in turn guarantees that the subtables won't be on the same line.  Remove the blank line, or replace it with a `%` at the beginning to make it into a comment.

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected now!